# Is there any application for a constexpr operator++(int) (post-increment)

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

The following code shows how a `constexpr operator++()` (pre-increment) can be used ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ol9kRlqHwob41cY1)). Now I wonder if there is any usefulness in declaring a post-increment operator as `constexpr`. I assume that such an operator has no side-effects and is used in a way similar as in the example. (If this is too abstract: I intend to extend my [bitset2](https://github.com/ClaasBontus/bitset2) class and want to know if there would be any benefit if the post-increment operator was `constexpr`.)

```
struct S {
  constexpr S( int i ) : m_i( i ) {}
  constexpr S & operator++() {
      ++m_i;
      return *this;
  }
  int m_i;
};

int main() {
  constexpr auto s1= ++S{3};  
  std::cout << s1.m_i << '\n'; // output: 4
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has an application: Having a post-increment operator defined could be useful for writing `constexpr` functions. Consider the following:

```
tempalte<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<baz,N> foo(){
    std::array<baz,N> bar;
    baz i;
    for(auto&& item: bar) {
        item = i++;
    }
    return bar;
}
```

The array `bar` in the example above will be filled at compile time via the `constexpr`. Say the type `baz` was some form of counter the order of operations (pre/post) for the increment could be important.

The thing to keep in mind is that a `constexpr` is an expression not just a value. There is allowed to be complex (within the rules for constexpr of course) calculations that go into a constexpr. In theory you could write many programs entirely as `constexpr` (though I am not saying it would be a good idea).

Comment: `return bar;`. Why are you double referencing `item` in the loop? You're not moving anything...

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius fixed the missing return statement. And no I am not moving anything, but the range based for loop is generating a temporary from dereferencing the iterator which I am capturing via an r-value reference rather than copying the value . It very well could be written in several other ways.

Comment: Yes, your example convinces me. I applied it to my initial example ([link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6k8Vuq1rVl0yM1M9)). Removing `constexpr ` for the post-increment operator will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's usefull, but you can duplicate your pre-increment example in a post-increment one

A compilable example

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
 {
   constexpr S (int i) : m_i{ i }
    { }

   constexpr S & operator++ ()
    {
      ++m_i;
      return *this;
    }

   constexpr S operator++ (int)
    {
      S ret { this->m_i ++ };
      return ret;
    }

   int m_i;
 };

int main()
 {
   constexpr S s1 { ++S{3} };  
   constexpr S s2 { S{4}++ };  

   static_assert( s1.m_i == s2.m_i, "!");
 }
```

And with both constexpr operators, you can write constexpr functions as

```
constexpr S foo (int a, int b)
 {
   S s1 { a };
   S s2 { b };

   bool test { (s1++).m_i == (++s2).m_i };

   return test ? s1 : s2;
 }
```

Comment: Repeating the logic isn't a good idea - you should just call `operator++()`.

Comment: @Barry - I know, but reasoning this way you can simply contruct `S` with an incremented value (`constexpr auto s1= S{4};`). It's useful a constexpr pre-increment operator? Anyway, I've added another function-based (but useful?) example.

Comment: You could just as well `return m_i++;`. Thanks to RVO it would result in the same thing anyway though.